# Django replaces underscore with whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a django app where user can upload a pdf and get it converted to .png. The upload part is working fine but when I try to convert the pdf file, it says file not found. I noticed something weird that the filename contains _ but when I print the name of the file uploaded, it converted _ to whitespace ( "file_1.pdf" to "file 1.pdf") and hence the reason for the error file not found! Why is django doing this? I haven't written any code to do so!!

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

class UploadPdf(models.Model):
    resumes = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])])
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from app1.models import UploadPdf
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput

class ResumeUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadPdf
        fields = ['resumes']
        widgets = {
            'resumes': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import ResumeUpload
from app1.models import UploadPdf
from app1.convert import convert_file
import os

def home(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ResumeUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
         files = request.FILES.getlist('resumes')
         
         if form.is_valid():
              f = form.save()
              f.user = request.user
              f.save()
             
              f_list = []
              
              file_name = form.cleaned_data['resumes'].name
              
              if files:
                  for i in files:
                       file_instance = UploadPdf(resumes=i)
                       f_list.append(file_instance.resumes.path)
                       file_instance.save()
                       
                  for j in f_list:
                      convert_file(j)
             
    else:
        form = ResumeUpload()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html' , {'form': form})
```

**convert.py**

```
import fitz, os

def convert_file(f_path):
    
    doc = fitz.open(f_path)
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f_path))[0]
    
    for page in doc:
        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        pix.save(name + '-' + str(page.number) + ".png")
          
    print('success!')
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem and was about to post a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution! Try the below code:-

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserUploadModel(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'file_uploads')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from app1.models import UserUploadModel

class UserUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = UserUploadModel
        fields = ['file']
        widgets = {
            'file' : ClearableFileInput(attrs = {'multiple': True}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import UserUploadForm
from app1.models import UserUploadModel
from app1.convert import convert_file
from app1.transfer import move_dir
import os
from project1 import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save()
            f.user = request.user
            f.save()
          
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
                        
            f_list = []
            
            if files:
                for i in files:
                    file_instance = UserUploadModel(file = i)
                    file_instance.save()
                    f_list.append(file_instance.file.path)

                [convert(j) for j in f_list]
                
            return redirect('app1-display')
        
    else:
        
        form = UserUploadForm()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'form' : form})
```

**home.html**

```
{%block content%}

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {%csrf_token%}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: Yes it works now! What exactly was I doing wrong??

Comment: @lowkey Don't know but maybe you were doing `getlist` before validating. That might be the reason!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import ResumeUpload
from app1.models import UploadPdf
from app1.convert import convert_file
import os

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ResumeUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
         files = request.FILES.getlist('resumes')
         
         if form.is_valid():
              f = form.save()
              f.user = request.user
              f.save()
             
              f_list = []
              
              file_name = form.cleaned_data['resumes'].name
              
              if files:
                  for i in files:
                       file_instance = UploadPdf(resumes=i)
                       f_list.append(file_instance.resumes.path)
                       file_instance.save()
                       
                  for j in f_list:
                      convert_file(j)
             
    else:
        form = ResumeUpload()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html' , {'form': form})
```

Comment: gandu same code copy paste kiya XD! Ruk report krta hu!